# React-player How to handle Play Pause state with autoplay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

I have a problem with the autoplay policy it completely messes my custom layout.

In the component, there is a "play" state by default set as true to trigger autoplay but after refreshing a page autoplay doesn't work even if the "play" state is set as true. Now the problem is when the user clicks on the play button, state doesn't change because it is already true, the solution is to set it false and again to true but in this solution, user has to click twice on the icon.

Can someone help me with that, maybe the react-player has already state or method to fire the play and I don't need a "play" state to handle play pause.

Here is a simple example how it works

```js
export default function Untitled() {
    const playerRef = useRef(null);
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(true)
    return (
    <div>
        <ReactPlayer
            style={{display:"none"}}
            controls={false}
            playing={playing}
            wrapper={"audio"}
            progressInterval={200}
            config={{
              file: {
                attributes: {preload: "auto"},
                forceAudio:true,
              },
            }}
        />
        <IconButton size="small">
            {playerRef && playerRef.current.player.isPlaying ? (
              <PauseIcon onClick={() => setPlaying(false)}/>
            ) : (
              <PlayArrowIcon onClick={() => setPlaying(true)}/>
            )}
        </IconButton>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: add your sample code. we need to know what you are doing in code

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not passing/assigning "ref" to the "ReactPlayer" component.

In this case, the ref is not necessary.

```
export default function Untitled() {
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(true)
    return (
    <div>
        <ReactPlayer
            style={{display:"none"}}
            controls={false}
            playing={playing}
            wrapper={"audio"}
            progressInterval={200}
            config={{
              file: {
                attributes: {preload: "auto"},
                forceAudio:true,
              },
            }}
        />
        <IconButton size="small">
            {playing? (
              <PauseIcon onClick={() => setPlaying(false)}/>
            ) : (
              <PlayArrowIcon onClick={() => setPlaying(true)}/>
            )}
        </IconButton>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Sadly it is, because if we use "playing" state to control icons and the autoplay policy block video user get a pause icon instead of play.

Comment: It looks like this https://ibb.co/mhD18Yx but video is not playing

Comment: Ok, then please assign the ref to the component properly, you haven't added ref to the component. https://github.com/CookPete/react-player/blob/HEAD/src/demo/App.js check this example of react player with ref. 
Note: This is a class component example

Comment: If you still facing the issue please raise an issue in React player GitHub. https://github.com/CookPete/react-player/issues.

Answer (score -1):

Solution

```js
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
    // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
  });
}
```